# Client Side, AXIOS POST http... net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, cors, xmlhttprequest

I'm using React and Express for my application. I work on a local network, on my computer, the request is made perfectly, but the other computers that are connected to the same network can't connect and make the request.

Server Side:

```js
const appExpress = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

appExpress.use(cors());
appExpress.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-   MD, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Ou domínios específicos
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); // Se necessário
    next();
});
appExpress.use(bodyParser.json());
appExpress.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

appExpress.post('', async (req, res) => {
    const {
        metodo
    } = req.body;
    const {
        parametros
    } = req.body;
    const {
        classe
    } = req.body;
    const retorno = await objClasses[classe][metodo](parametros);

    return res.send(JSON.stringify(retorno));
});

appExpress.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log('ouvindo 3030');
});
```

Client Side:

```js
export async function ChamaRotina(
    classe: string,
    metodo: string,
    parametros: any
) {
    const retorno = await axios.post('http://192.168.170.204:3030/', {
        classe,
        metodo,
        parametros,
    });
    return retorno.data;
}
```

I've already tried opening the ports through the firewall, changing the used port (in my case, 3030), I've tried adding all possible headers on the server side, passing parameters to cors(), and I couldn't get it to work. I just need the request to be made.
The message error was: [error at console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TRTi.png)

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what error message? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, that's the error message

Comment: Nothing else? Then it's likely not a CORS error.

Comment: Well, this is the only error message that appears besides the AxiosError message